# Getting the line in which occurrence of words in files appear?

Tags: python

In the quote below is my question. I am able to get the output as indicated but I am failing to get the numbers before it as indicated in the question in which the occurrence of words appear in.

> Write a function definition for the following function and then invoke
>   the function to test it works. The function:
>
> `search_file(filename, searchword)`
>
> should accept a filename (a file fields.txt has been
>   provided on Moodle) and a user specified search word. It searches
>   every line in the file for an occurrence of the word and if it exists
>   it prints out the line preceded by the line number. Importantly it
>   also writes the same output out to a file called `fieldsModified.txt`.

For example:

```
search_file("Fields-of-Athenry", "watched")
```

The output of the above should be in the following format:

```
9 - Where once we watched the small free birds fly.
21 - Where once we watched the small free birds fly.
26 - She watched the last star falling
33 - Where once we watched the small free birds fly."
```

Comment: What does your current code look like that only gives you the text?

Comment: You forgot to include the code. If it's too long and/or large parts are not relevant, make it a [mcve].

Comment: If you want numbers for an iteration, look at `enumerate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of ways you could do this; I think this is the most straightforward:

```
def search_file(filename, searchword):
    my_file = open(filename)
    output_file = open('fieldsModified.txt', 'w+')

    for i, line in enumerate(my_file):
        if searchword in line:
            print( str(i) + ' - ' + line )
            output_file.write( str(i) + ' - ' + line )

    my_file.close()
    output_file.close()
```

Whether this is suitable for your needs depends on how large are the files you need to search, whether you care about uppercase vs lowercase etc. I'm not sure whether this directly addresses the problem you are having, so if I'm missing what you were trying to ask please say so...

Comment: Hey thanks, your method works if i call back the function and pass in the values.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def search_file(filename, searchword):
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(filename)]

    lineCount = 1
    results = []
    for line in lines:

        if searchword in line:
            results.append(str(lineCount) + "-" + line)
        lineCount += 1

    with open('fieldsModified.txt', 'w') as f:
        for item in results:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)

    for each in results:
        print(each)


search_file('fields.txt', 'watched')
```

Comment: Do add some details why you use this approach and how this will work as opposed toOP's code.

Comment: Thanks Dos, your method works perfectly as it takes you step into each line on what is going through.